# How can I inform the Gallery about the touch event happening in ScrollView?

Tags: java, android

I have the following custom classes. Currently the scroll for the ScrollView works fine. If I override the onTouchEvent in ScrollView and make it return false, the Gallery works fine however the ScrollView scroll does not. How can I make it so both will work together?

This is the CardGallery class which extends Gallery:

```
public class CardGallery extends Gallery {
    public CardGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CardGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        //return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        //return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }
}
```

This is the CardScrollView class which extends ScrollView:

```
public class CardScrollView extends ScrollView {
    public CardScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CardScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried overriding the onTouchEvent in the Gallery class to return false?

AFAIK, if you override an android event method and return true, Android will assume you have handled the event completely.  If you return false, the event will be passed on to the next handler.

Comment: I am aware. Do you know how to inform the gallery of the touch event and also have the ScrollView work? I'm pretty sure what I have to do is get the CardScrollView onTouchEvent event and pass it to the CardGallery's onTouchEvent method but I'm not familiar on how I should do this.

Comment: override OnTouchEvent in the ScrollView, if it is up or down call `super` if it is left or right return false.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it doesn't seem to work for some reason? Look below.